# How can I resize pixel art in Pyglet without making it blurry?

Tags: python, image, pyglet

I have a tileset of 8x8 pixel images, and I want to resize them in my game so they'd be double that (16x16 pixels, e.g. turning each pixel into a 2x2 block.) What I'm trying to achieve is a Minecraft-like effect, where you have small pixel images scale to larger blockier pixels.

In Pyglet, the sprite's `scale` property blurs the pixels. Is there some other way?

**Working Code:**

Here's the solution that works (thanks to DMan's persistence and Jimmy's insight):

```
image = resource.image('tileset.png')                                                                                                                                                               
texture = image.get_texture()   
gl.glTexParameteri(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.GL_NEAREST)                                                                                                                               
texture.width = 16 # resize from 8x8 to 16x16                                                                                                                                                                  
texture.height = 16                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
texture.blit(100, 30) # draw
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Pyglet enough to make this an answer, but I saw that you can use OpenGL, so `from pyglet.gl import *` and then make a call to http://www.talisman.org/opengl-1.1/Reference/glTexParameter.html with `GL_NEAREST`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that, but I've never used OpenGL before. Kind of new to graphics programming :\

Comment: I don't know how much Pyglet does behind the scenes, but something like this could work: `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`. Then let's say you had a call to `a = image.load('blah.jpg')`. Assign `tex = a.texture` then `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.id)` and finally a call to `pyglet.gl.glTexParameteri(pyglet.gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, pyglet.gl.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, pyglet.gl.GL_NEAREST)`. I'm not too familiar with the namespace for OpenGL in python, so the I left the full call qualified. Since we imported OpenGL, I believe you can remove _at least_ the pyglet in the front, and maybe _gl_ too.

Comment: Hey I tried it without success, could you double check my code in the update? Also, do you have any good resources to help me understand these GL commands? I appreciate the help.

Comment: One thing I noticed immediately is that you set the texture width and height _before_ your call to `glTexParameteri`. OpenGL 1/2/~3 which I presume Pyglet is based on have these *immediate mode* commands. That is, you execute a command to change the state, then everything after it will change. I'd begin by moving the calls underneath the gl calls.

Comment: Changed it, but no dice. Any other ideas?

Comment: `MAG_FILTER` maybe.

Comment: I took a look at Pyglet issue #463 and it seemed to have patched support for this without OpenGL calls yourself. Seems like `pyglet.image.Texture.create_for_size` allows you to set min and mag filters on `internal_format`. The declaration is `def create_for_size(cls, target, min_width, min_height, internalformat=None): internalformat=None, min_filter=GL_LINEAR, mag_filter=GL_LINEAR):`

Comment: Thanks guys, I got it working! I just had to switch to GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, and it stopped blurring the image. I really appreciate the help; I'm going to try and understand OpenGL a little more, though.

Comment: Oops, did you use my code of `pyglet.gl.glTexParameteri(pyglet.gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, pyglet.gl.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, pyglet.gl.GL_NEAREST)`? If so, sorry, I knew it was MAG_FILTER in the back of my head... Glad to see it worked anyhow. As for OpenGL resources, you can check out the iconic OpenGL Red book. Do note that this is _not modern OpenGL_. I do believe Pyglet binds version 3 or lower though, and concepts can still be gleamed. For example, http://glprogramming.com/red/chapter09.html for textures. I recommend you posting an answer to this question or I can do it as well.

Comment: @DMan: could you post a summary of your comments as an answer, so that this question can be flagged correctly as answered?

Comment: Great, I'm bookmarking that. Go ahead an post a summary of your solution, so I can mark this as answered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the request of commenters...

*Warning to Pyglet professionals: There may be a nice Pyglet way to do this, and this isn't it. It's a nice OpenGL way. You have been warned!*

You can do this in OpenGL by first binding the texture, then calling `glTexParameteri` or similar varients. You can do this in Pyglet by importing OpenGL:

`from pyglet.gl import *`

You can then enable `GL_TEXTURE_2D` to set the target. This is not always needed, but I'm keeping this complete for some other bindings.

`glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`

In Pyglet, it seems like you don't have to bind the texture either. Sometimes you have to load in your image, get the texture id, then use `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.id)`. My assumption that these are already the state set for you in Pyglet.

The next step is to call `glTexParameteri`. Thanks to Jimmy on correcting me on this: the correct call is:

`gl.glTexParameteri(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.GL_NEAREST)`

A quick break down: the first is just to set the target so OpenGL knows what you're talking about, then the second parameter is the type of filter you would like to set. `MAG_FILTER` is correct  because it controls the magnifications of textures. The final parameter is `GL_NEAREST`, which controls how the texture is scaled. `GL_NEAREST` is basically a fast scale that gives pixel-styled textures. `GL_LINEAR` is normal and will instead smoothly blur your texture.

This version of OpenGL I'm talking about (about < OpenGL 3.2 officially) uses immediate mode, which sets the state. Now that the state is set, you can scale your texture. I can see no better than to show the code that Renold himself posted as working code.

```
image = resource.image('tileset.png')                                                                                                                                                               
texture = image.get_texture()   
gl.glTexParameteri(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.GL_NEAREST)                                                                                                                               
texture.width = 16 # resize from 8x8 to 16x16                                                                                                                                                                  
texture.height = 16                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
texture.blit(100, 30) # draw
```

Comment: Renold, if you could take a look at this and suggest improvements, that'd be great. I'm interested in something though. If you remove `texture = image.get_texture()`, does that work? It seems like you never called it, unless that binds the texture internally.

Comment: Yeah, turns out you don't need it. I eventually just put the image into a sprite, and it worked fine: 
`image = resource.image('tileset.png') \n`
`sprite = sprite.Sprite(image, x_pos, y_pos) \n`
`sprite.scale = 2 \n`

Answer (score 4):

For those like me, who are simply making a retro-style game where they want EVERYTHING scaled to be pixelated, the simple quick answer is start your code with:

```
from pyglet.gl import *
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
```

Then all your usage of sprites, etc. from there on out stay nice and pixelated.

Answer (score 2):

Modern pyglet lets you set the default texture filtering by modifying a couple class attributes on `Texture`. Pyglet docs even [explicitly mention "retro style pixel art games"](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming_guide/image.html#texture-filtering).

Here's an example. With the following project structure...

```
asteroids/
    game/
        __init__.py
        asteroid.py
        player.py
        resources.py
    resources/
        asteroid.png
        flame.png
        spaceship.png
    asteroids.py
```

...you can have the following code in `asteroids.py` (the main game logic, where you first import pyglet):

```
# Set default texture filtering for pixel art.
from pyglet.gl import GL_NEAREST
from pyglet.image import Texture

Texture.default_mag_filter = Texture.default_min_filter = GL_NEAREST

# Do your other imports.
import pyglet

from game import asteroid, player, resources
```

Now your pixel art scales nicely.