# pyglet how to disable image smoothing?

Tags: pyglet

I'm using sprites made up of very few pixels. When scaling the sprite gets blurry, so how do I disable this smoothing? I couldn't find anything in the docs or elsewhere online

Sprite:

[image: sprite]

In pyglet, scaled 8:
[image: in pyglet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution at [Scaling window contents in Pyglet?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31009/scaling-window-contents-in-pyglet?rq=1)

```
from pyglet.gl import *
```

then add

```
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST) 
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
```

to on_draw()